# jackson serialize reference with partial information

Tags: java, json, jackson

Suppose I have 2 types of entity:

```
Owner{
  String name;
  @OneToMany
  List<Hotel> hotels;
}

Hotel{
  String name;
  String address;
  int price;
}
```

I want to serialize these entity as:

```
owner: 
{
  "name":"xxx",
  "hotels": [{"name":x, "price":1}]
}

hotel:
{
  "name":"x",
  "address": "111 yyy",
  "price": 1
}
```

Basically I want to only display a partial information of hotel in owner serialization, but full information in hotel serialization.
Is there a way to do this beside a customized serializer of Owner?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at Jackson Views? http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation

Comment: @dnault It seems very similar to a customized serializer, I have to create extra class. Is there a way to just use annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation from jackson-annotations package.

```
public class Owner {

    private String name;
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("address")
    private List<Hotel> hotels;
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thanks.